# Kendo ListView and MVVM 'edit template' cancel button resets bound data to initial state

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-listview

I have a Kendo ListView bound to an Observable object and all is working well.

I'm able to:

- Add items to the list
- Edit existing items by using the edit template below
- Delete items

One oddity though is when I switch an item to edit view and click Cancel it resets all data back to the original data. So if I started with one item with say name and amount fields, I edit the item and change the amount, then add two more items to the list all is well. But then I click edit on any of the items and immediately click cancel, from here it removes all the additional items I added and resets the data for the first item back to what it was at the beginning.

Why would the cancel action do that?

This dojo snippet shows the exact problem I'm having: http://dojo.telerik.com/IKowo

Kendo version **2016.3.1118**

**EDIT**: 
One further development, I found a forum post on Telerik stating that you have to have an ID column and a schema:model:id setup otherwise things won't work as expected.

I've updated the dojo snippet as follows: http://dojo.telerik.com/IKowo/2

Since adding the ID to the mix it looks like the amounts aren't being affected by the cancel button but the newly added items still get removed.

Comment: This will probably not solve the issue that you are facing but it might give you a hint. I noticed that when you edit a newly added entry and hit cancel the getData() method is called but when you do the same with one of the original entries that doesn't happen. 

I usually use the fluent api of the kendo grid so I am not familiar enough with the non-fluent syntax to be able to help you. If you are open to using the fluent api I can post code that will achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: @univ if you're referring to the fluent API in c# then unfortunately that wouldn't help. But, you've spotted something that will be useful so thank you.

Comment: @Jacques did you manage to find a solution to this problem? I am also facing the same issues. I tried using CRUD with Local Data. But still the new data is deleted on cancel event.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the example provided here by telerik

//Binding Listview to local data array & Perform CRUD
http://dojo.telerik.com/eWih/2

The Only Requirement for the cancel event not deleting the new Items is:

- The id field should be kept 0 when adding the new item to the datasource
- It should be incremented / Updated in the datasource transport.create event (REQUIRED)

happy coding!